# Unexplained keywords in Swift: left, none, right, Type. What do they do?

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I've been reading Apple's Swift Programming Language book (the version updated for Swift 2.0) and I've found something rather curious.
In `Language Reference` > `Lexical Stricture` > `Keywords and Punctuation` ([link here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html) - but you need to scroll down a bit) there's a list of language keywords. A few of them haven't been explained anywhere.

> Keywords reserved in particular contexts: associativity, convenience, dynamic, didSet, final, get, infix, inout, lazy, **left**, mutating, **none**, nonmutating, optional, override, postfix, precedence, prefix, Protocol, required, **right**, set, **Type**, unowned, weak, and willSet. Outside the context in which they appear in the grammar, they can be used as identifiers.

Do you have any clue what they do/mean or where to find applicable information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`left`, `right` and `none` are used to specify the associativity of a custom operator:

> The associativity of an operator specifies how a sequence of operators with the same precedence level are grouped together in the absence of grouping parentheses. You specify the associativity of an operator by writing the context-sensitive keyword associativity followed by the associativity, which is one of the context-sensitive keywords left, right, or none.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/associativity

`Type` is used with meta-types:

> A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types, structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.
>
> The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of that type followed by .Type.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/metatype-type

Comment: here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html at Metatype Type section, you can find about `Type`

Comment: Yup, found it right after posting. Thanks @DánielNagy!

Comment: Now my question would be about the difference between .Type and .self as in MyClass.Type and MyClass.self

Comment: @BR41N-FCK That's explained in the article of the 2nd link Guillaume gave— just search the page for _“.Type”_ .  In short, `.Type` gives you the metatype as a type _(useful for specifying a variable's type or for a `typealias`)_ while `.self` gives you the metatype as a value _(useful for storing in a variable)_.  From Apple's example code, `let metatype: AnotherSubClass.Type = AnotherSubClass.self`—so basically `AnotherSubClass.self` returns a value of type `AnotherSubClass.Type`.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Umm how do I put this... you realize I submitted my question in 2015? And now it is completely outdated :-)

Comment: @BR41N-FCK 1. Stack Overflow is not just for the person asking a question, it's for everyone that comes along in the future with the same question. People continue to have this strange idea that SO is a forum, but in reality it was designed from day one as an anti-forum.  2. It's not outdated. Check the links above. They're (now) to Swift 5 docs. The original question, this answer, your sub-question, and my answer to that are all still the same in 2019 for Swift 5 as they were in 2015 for Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 4):

`left`, `right` and `none` are used for associativity ordering when declaring operators, such as:

```
infix operator ⊕ { associativity left precedence 140 }
```

See [the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID380)